# Covariance and Expected value of product of random variables definitions going in circles

Tags: probability, expected-value, covariance

I am trying to get a refresher on basic statistical theory and I found myself in an awkward position.

The definition of covariance from wikipedia is:

$cov(X,Y) = E[X,Y] - E[X]E[Y]$

Ok fair enough, I know how to calculate the right hand side, but I am not sure what to do with the left.

So then I searched for "expected value of product of random variables"

And that returned:
$E[XY] = cov(X,Y) + E[X]E[Y]$

Which isn't particularly helpful, I am also able to reorder the terms of an equation.

My goal is merely to understand the definition of covariance in a way I can compute it. But I have not been able to find a resource that defines the expected value of a product of random variables without relying on the definition of covariance.

Comment: $XY$ is another random variable, call it $Z$, then $\mathbb E[XY] = \mathbb E[Z]$. However, there is different approach. You probably should have information about joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, call it $\mu$. Let $f(x,y)=xy$. Then $\mathbb E[XY] = \mathbb E[f(X,Y)] = \int f(x,y) d\mu(x,y) = \int xy d\mu(x,y)$

Comment: Why $f(x,y)=xy$ is this an arbitrary choice for the sake of explanation, or a general pattern?

Comment: You want to compute $\mathbb E[XY]$ so it is natural to consider object $XY$ that can be obtained from vector $(X,Y)$ with known distribution. A way to obtain it is by considering $f(x,y) = xy$. When you would like to calculate $\mathbb E [ e^X 
 \sin(Y) ]$ you probably would be interested in function $g(x,y) = e^x \sin(y)$, et cetera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition for covariance of two random variables, is that it is the expected product of their displacements from their means.

$$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf E((X-\mathsf E(X))\,(Y-\mathsf E(Y)))$$

Which gives us that:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)&=\mathsf E(XY-X\,\mathsf E(Y)-Y\,\mathsf E(X)+\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(Y))\\&=\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X\,\mathsf E(Y))-\mathsf E(Y\,\mathsf E(X))+\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(Y))\\&=\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(Y)-\mathsf E(Y)\,\mathsf E(X)+\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(Y)\\&=\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(Y)
\end{align}$$

The covariance of a random variable and itself is called the variance.$$\begin{split}\mathsf{Var}(X)&=\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)\\&=\mathsf E((X-\mathsf E(X))^2)\\&=\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2\end{split}$$

The usefulness of covariance is that comparing it to the product of the variances (more specifically to the square root of that product) gives a measure for how linearly dependent the two random variables may be. This is the correlation coefficient.

$$\mathsf{Corr}(X,Y)=\dfrac{\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)}{\surd(\mathsf{Var}(X)\,\mathsf{Var}(Y))}$$